# How do I cascade start multiple gifs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gif

I have a gif of a candle with an animated flame. My webpage will show a few of these gifs in a row. It would be much more realistic if all the gifs didn't start at once after the page loads (otherwise I get a line of 'synchronised' candles).

I can create multiple gifs with different flame animations and then randomise which ones get shown but this will take extra bandwidth and will add an extra level of complexity.

Is there a way to maybe cascade start the gifs? i.e. start each one after a random amount of time in order that they are out of synch and look a bit more realistic?

Maybe using jquery? Or simple javascript?

Many thanks

Comment: AFAIK you don't have control on the timeline of GIF's from javascript... so I'm quite sure this is not possible as such. That said, unless you plan to host your site in the 90's through a time machine, I would say an animated gif of a candle is a VERY bad idea anyway, so no matter if they start together or not, your site will look crappy. Just saying...

Comment: Why don't you add the images dynamically, at intervals?

Comment: GIFs will start animating after they are loaded into the DOM. You could delay this load using `setTimeout` and display a static image of the first frame of the GIF in the meantime.

Comment: Ian and Sean are right: small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H9arV/

Comment: Once an gif has been loaded, additional images created with the same source will all be synced to the same timeframe as the original, eg: http://jsfiddle.net/tm2b2/1/. You'll either have to use different gifs, or to reduce requests, create a single large width gif with multiple candles at different instances on it. Neither option is particularly nice.

Comment: @MLeFevre Nice, didn't realize that

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will experiment with the setTimeout option. @Bartdude I'm actually changing to gifs because the original site used Flash - which looked great but has compatibility problems with Safari etc. If the setTimeout doesn't pan out then I'll just have to create several versions and increment them as they are used so two the same don't appear next to each other. Thank you :-)

Comment: That said, maybe a more modern way of doing this migh be to somehow use canvas, CSS animations, etc ... ? yeah I know, I really hate animated gif's, but I've seen enough of it in the 90's for my whole life :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.
If you place the same image on multiple places, it's going to always look the same.
You could edit the image and change the order of the frames within the gif, save and repeat this a few times, and then load the gifs, but this will only work if the images are already loaded (cached) on your browser.
If this is the first time you load the page, it could just happen that an image will be loaded exactly when another image started from the first frame of the loaded image, so it will look as if they are in sync.

You could load the images using `setTimeout` but this will have the same problem as described above when the user first enters your page. You can delay the request for loading the file, but you have no control of the speed in which the file will be downloaded and therefor no control on when exactly the first frame will start playing.

If I were you, I'd try creating a big sprite of different images, each starting the animation from a different frame. There will be only one request and all animations will play together, making sure frames are never in sync.
When displaying the images on the site, make sure to properly show only the part you want for each image. This will give you the effect of flames burning at random times.

Comment: Thanks Narxx - can you elaborate on what you mean by making a big sprite of different images? Do you mean a large gif with lots of candles on it and then use CSS somehow to select an area of the large gif to display (in order to display just one gif)? Or are you talking about something else? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not in narxx's head, but you indeed gave the definition of a sprite in this context.

Comment: Yes, John. This is exactly what I meant. Put all your different GIFs in one big GIF file (sprite) and then you could select which part of the image to show using CSS.
This is just like working with regular sprites only not as background images (since background doesn't support animated GIFs).
You could position the image in its container, giving the container a `overflow: hidden` rule, hiding the rest of the big sprite image.